# Displaying Flair on my Facebook Timeline

Tags: discussion, flair, facebook

Is there any way I show off my Stack exchange Flair on my Facebook Timeline?

Pasting the HTML code snippet as a "Status Update" just gives a link to my SE Profile.

Also is there any way I can make it appear as the first post in Facebook forever?

Comment: http://stackapps.com seems to have a couple of Facebook related "apps" to show off flair/participation. Don't know how good/useful they are though.

Comment: I feel like this should be a technical question because I *can* see a way to implement this.  Partially at least.. But no, there is no "official" way to promote your flair on Facebook.  You could always same the resulting flair image file and post it as updates...

Comment: @Lix You mean I should ask this on SO main site and not meta? Or may be in superuser.com?

Comment: I don't think it's a good question to ask on SO because it would look like a "do it for me" style question that would get shot down instantly.

Comment: This would be wrong on SO because it's not programming-related, and wrong on SU because it's not hardware- or software-related. It doesn't quite fit here at MSO, either... at best, it's standing on the line between on- and off-topic, waggling its fingers over the off-topic side. Ultimately, this is a "how do I use Facebook" question, so the most appropriate site would be Web Apps SE.

Comment: I guess this could be better asked on stackapps.com or webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

- In its current form your question could only be answered with something on Facebook, so its off-topic here on meta.
- If it is a feature request - you'll need to refine it before officially submitting a request.

---

I'll address two main issues here -

**`1.`** This feels to me like a [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) technical question.

I won't discuss the technicalities here because its not what we are *here* for.  However as [mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131691/displaying-flair-on-my-facebook-timeline#comment363494_131691), it might be considered a [please do my research for me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937)  question.  You'd have to come with a slightly more specific question such as "How do I load an image into an SWF using ActionScipt 3". A question which showed that you have researched your issue, have a plan, and are having difficulties implementing a certain part of it.

**`2.`** This might be appropriate on meta if it were a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

If you like, you can turn this into a feature request. Don't forget to make

- mock-ups
- screen shots
- free hand red circles
- funny analogies
- lots of cool formatting
- and such.

Because convincing people to make SO more compliant with [social-networking](/questions/tagged/social-networking) is a debate/argument/*discussion* that has been had many-a-time... You'll have to present a solid argument and show that the site **and the community** would benefit from a feature like this. 
One could argue that what you are asking for could simply be an image that you upload to Facebook.  Low-tech as it is, it has the same effect.

Comment: But flair updates every 24/36 hrs; while the image would never automatically update; it would have to be done manually every time - and no one's gonna be that crazy to do that.

Comment: @myselfpoddar if you really wanted something like that, you could set up a script or a macro or write your own FB app that does it for you. ;)